# Google APIs Service Agent service account deleted by mistake

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google APIs Service Agent service account deleted by mistake in google console, how to recover it.

I successfully created other service account using cloud console, how to recover this one, Please guide

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Resolved using this in gcloud console:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT_ID> \
  --member serviceAccount:<PROJECT_NUMBER>@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role roles/editor
```

`<PROJECT_NUMBER>`, a 12-digit number, may be obtained from the output of `gcloud project list`, or, in case your project list is really uncomfortably long, from the string `<PROJECT_ID>` with
`gcloud projects describe <PROJECT_ID> --format='get(projectNumber)'`.

Comment: I'm wondering what functionality did you lose by removing permission from the API Agent? I routinely remove it from some project, when the Recommender suggests it. BTW, please mark the green checkmark on your own answer, it is both correct and useful!

Comment: @kkm, without this, I wasn't able to launch a rabbitmq bitnami product from the GCP marketplace the API uses this service account